# If S is a bounded set, then inf(S) and sup(s) belong to the closure of S

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

My proof:

Since $\bar S = S\cup bdy(S)$ $\Rightarrow S\subset \bar{S}$

and since S is bounded
$\Rightarrow inf(S)$ and $sup(S)$ exist

Then is it safe to assume that since inf(S) and sup(S) exists, then inf(S) and sup(s) is already a subset of $\bar S$?

Comment: No, you can't just assume that. You need to prove it.

Comment: so, i need to show that inf(s) and sup(s) is an element of S? isnt that the existence of an inf(s) and sup(s) means that they are already an element of the set S? Im confused.

Comment: No, $\inf S$ and $\sup S$ do not have to be elements of $S$. Saying that they exist simply means that they are elments of $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $\sup(S)$ is the real number $M$ such that $x \leq M$ for all $x \in S$, and such that if $M'$ also satisfies this inequality, then $M' \geq M$.

So let $M = \sup(S)$, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Now, for each $n$, let $a_n \in S$ be such that $\left| M - a_n \right| < \delta_n$. This exists by the definition of $\sup$, for if we could not find such an $a_n$, then we would have that $x \leq M - \delta_n$ for all $x \in S$, contradicting that $M$ is the $\sup$.

Now, by construction, we have $a_n \in S$ for all $n$ and $a_n \rightarrow M$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So by definition of closure, $M \in \bar{S}$.

The proof for $\inf$ is similar.

Comment: No $M$ doesn't have to be in the closure, for example(as Mathgemini gave) $S=(0,1)$ with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$. e.g. $(1-\frac{1}{n})$ is cauchy but do not converge!

Comment: @Qidi it is clear from the use of inf and sup that this question considers S to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, where this result is in fact true.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't entirely safe. It's better to mention that $\inf(S)$, $\sup{S}$ are limit points of $S$, i.e. there exist sequences $S\supset(x_n)\longrightarrow\inf(S)$ and $S\supset(y_n)\longrightarrow\sup(S)$, and that the closure contains all limit points, which follows easily from any possible definition.

But it is not true in general that $\inf(S)$, $\sup(S)$ belong to $S$! Note e.g. $S=(0, 1)$.